# Is it better to store nonce/timestamp information in my database or in a session?

Tags: oauth, nonce

I'm trying to temporarily store nonce/timestamp info to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks when performing OAuth authentication.  Is there any advantage to storing this info in a database over using $_SESSION?  My feeling is that $_SESSION would be faster.  However, I'm not sure if there's a security issue that I'm missing.

Comment: something wrong with https?

Comment: If your Session contain session management to store session info, then use a session.